# EmrCreateJobFlowOperator returns "ERROR - The conn_id `emr_default` isn't defined"

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr

I am using Airflow in EKS for a project. I am using the EmrCreateJobFlowOperator to create a new EMR cluster. When the Dag runs the step fails and I get an error:

{taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - The conn_id `emr_default` isn't defined

Here is my step in the code:

```
job_flow_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='create_job_flow',
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default',
        dag=dag
    )
```

I am using Airflow 1.10.11, and I know this is probably not an issue in later versions, but it's difficult for me to upgrade the version at the moment. I found other threads that advise on going into Airflow Connections and adding a new connection, but I don't know how to set that connection up and I cannot find resources on the subject.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should create conection of `emr_default` of the right type for the operator (you have to pick the right one from the list) .

Here is a detailed instruction on what to do. This is is "1.10.11" Airlfow documentation and if you need any other airflow resources and docs you can always go there and use "Saerch" functionality. I got to that page by choosing Airlfow 1.10.11 version and searching for "connection".

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.11/howto/connection/index.html?highlight=connections

Comment: Thank you. So I set up the connection using Conn Type "Elastic MapReduce" since I'm trying to start an emr cluster. I gave a login and password for a user that has admin access, but I did not know what else to provide. Are Host, Schema, and Port required in this case? Any Extras I have to add?

I tried to run just with the fields I entered and now I am getting this error:
ERROR - An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: Service role and InstanceProfile are required for calls made with temporary credentials provided by STS

Comment: Look at the documentation of the provider.

Comment: I don't understand the point of creation of connection since it should specify host/port and I literally don't have them until cluster will be created.

Comment: Okay, I've got it. emr_default is basically the same as aws_default, e.g. access/secret keys and region.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following connection of `emr_default` that works for me.

```
Connection Id: emr_default  
Connection Type: Amazon Elastic MapReduce  
Login: access_key  
Password: secret_key  
Extra: {"region_name": "eu-west-3"}
```

Replace "eu-west-3" with your region

Comment: @cursorrux  To be honest, I don't understand what did you modify or add

Comment: [@Michel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18541323/michel-ombessa) I'm just placed plain text code in the code format for more readability. Nothing more than that.